# ceiling box has 2 black wires 2 white 1 ground

Tags: electrical

I took old light fixture off. So I didn't take a picture of connections and had to replace junction box so i forgot how wire were connected. I know which white wire is hot. So I connected black on light fixture to white wire, capped other black wire,capped white wire from fixture and other white together. The light fixture is controlled by a switch which seems to be controlling bathroom and part of a bedroom. When switch is in on position bathroom,bedroom work. when switch is in off position ceiling light comes on and bathroom,bedroom power is off.

Comment: Usually white is neutral, not hot...

Comment: definitely hot used voltage tester

Comment: Did you use a non-contact voltage tester or a multi-meter? The non-contact testers that light up and beep when there is voltage are notorious for false positives. Also, there may be voltage on a neutral because it is the return path for the current coming out of the hot. All that being said, I am not an electrician...just babbling out things I have read while lurking here for a while.

Comment: If you take pictures you might get help from the electricians. They will likely want to see pictures of the switch box that controls this fixture, as well as the ceiling box.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the insides of both boxes involved please?

Comment: The white could be legitimately hot as part of a switch loop. "Capped a black" is likely the problem - if it wasn't capped before then a fixture replacement wouldn't have it capped now. Beyond that, need to see pictures.